# Tax query with multiple terms in pre_get_posts

Tags: terms, array, pre-get-posts, tax-query

I am trying to use a tax query in my `pre_get_posts` function. All is working but not when the array has multiple IDs. Let's say my URL looks like: ?listing_cat[]=1&listing_cat[]=2

Now I am trying to filter out posts that are in those 2 categories. But my filter only gets the posts from the first category ID. I guess I will need a foreach function, but I am not sure how to implement this. Currently I have the code below. Now I know I can use filter by multiple terms with a comma, like : `'terms' => array($rt_cat_id[0], $rt_cat_id[1])`, but I just need it to automatically get all the terms from the array `$rt_cat_id` and use those to filter the posts. How to accomplish that? Thanks

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_tax_archive' );
function rt_tax_archive($query) {
$rt_cat_id = $_GET['listing_cat'];

if( isset( $rt_cat_id ) && ! empty( $rt_cat_id[0] ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'listing_category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array($rt_cat_id[0]),
           );
        }       


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

`'terms' => $rt_cat_id`

I'll work for both array and single-based values.

Or you can simplify your code as follows:

```php
if( isset( $_GET[ 'listing_cat' ] ) ) {
   $tax_query[] = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $_GET[ 'listing_cat' ]
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the working code can be found below:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rt_tax_archive' );
function rt_tax_archive($query) {
$rt_cat_id = $_GET['listing_cat'];

if( isset( $rt_cat_id ) && ! empty( $rt_cat_id[0] ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $rt_cat_id,
            ),
        );
        }       


}
```